# Interpolation with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, fps

Is there a way to interpolate frames with ffmpeg? and not just copy them. I tried slowmovideo and boy it is slow.
I used Twixtor in vegas and hated it.
I gave megui and could not get it properly set up.

So is there a way to interpolate with ffmpeg??

Comment: The [framerate filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate) does some simple interpolation, but probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes a bit more advanced feature would be nice

Comment: FFmpeg recently got its own [minterpolate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate) filter.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, there is a way. Since November 2016, the libavfilter library has a video filter called [minterpolate](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate), which performs motion interpolation.

Example usage:

`ffmpeg -i input.lowfps.hevc -filter "minterpolate='fps=120'" output.120fps.hevc`

Comment: Just like any other ffmpeg video filter, e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.hevc -filter "minterpolate='mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1'" output.hevc`. The filter's documentation contains the description of the available parameters and their values.

Comment: This command didn't work for me until I specified `-filter:v` instead of just `-filter`

Comment: Yes, that is true. If there are some non-video streams in the input file, the `minterpolate` filter needs to be restricted to a single video stream by using the `:v` stream specifier. If the input file contains multiple video streams, it is necessary to restrict the filter to a single video stream by using a stream specifier similar to `:v:0`.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this AI project with impressive results: http://jianghz.me/projects/superslomo/

It has a Python implementation which can accelerate using CUDA. https://github.com/avinashpaliwal/Super-SloMo

There's also an easy tutorial for that Python impl, with honest examples. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXwXtIiOjRA

Answer (score 3):

You can use Butterflow as it uses ffmpeg
https://github.com/dthpham/butterflow

> It's a command-line tool that can:
>
> Increase a video's frame rate by rendering new frames based on motion
>   (pixel-warping + blending). Make smooth motion videos (simple blending
>   between frames). Leverage new frames/increase in frame rates to make
>   fluid slow motion videos.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.